# Adding new table row after td's full

Tags: javascript, html

After seventh day, new table row should be added. And if the user add new value it should be added td which added recently. The frustrating point is, I don't know how to manipulate DOM's for this situation.

```
  const workInput = document.querySelector('#workInput')
    const workForm = document.querySelector('#workForm')
    const workBtn = document.querySelector('#workButton')
    const tableTd = document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr td')
    const tableTr = document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr')
    workForm.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
        tableTr.forEach(function(tr){
            tr.innerHTML+=
            `  <td>${workInput.value}</td>   `
        })
       e.preventDefault()
    })


    table{
        margin: 1rem auto;
        width: 1000px;
        background-color: rgb(54, 180, 238);
    }
    tr{
        background-color: aliceblue;
    }
    tr:nth-child(odd){
        background-color: antiquewhite; 
    }
    td{
        text-align: center;
    }



      <div>
           <form autocomplete="off" action="#" id="workForm">
            <input type="text" id="workInput">
            <button id="workButton">Add</button>
           </form>
            <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>First day</th>
                    <th>Second day</th>
                    <th>Third day</th>
                    <th>Fourth day</th>
                    <th>Fifth day</th>
                    <th>Sixth day</th>
                    <th>Seventh day</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I tried many ways for that, couldn't find properly method. Many forEach algorithms, DOM manipulation, but still I have no idea. Any idea for that situation? Btw, I need to create with vanilla js, not any plugin, or Jquery.
Hope, everything is clear, if not just comment for more details, please. Thanks for all responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   // i added 
  let days = 7;
  let workCount = 0;


  const workInput = document.querySelector("#workInput");
  const workForm = document.querySelector("#workForm");
  const workBtn = document.querySelector("#workButton");
  const tableTd = document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr td");
  
  // I changed it from const to let and querySelectorAll all to querySelectorA
  let tableTr = document.querySelector("table tbody tr");

  const tableBody = document.querySelector("table tbody");

  workForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (workCount < days) {
      tableTr.innerHTML += `<td>${workInput.value}</td>`;
      workCount++;
    }
    if (workCount === days) {
      workCount = 0;
      let newRow = document.createElement("tr");
      tableTr = newRow;
      tableBody.appendChild(newRow);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `childElementCount` to check the number of elements in a row and use `appendChild` to add a new row.

#### HTML code

```
    <div>
      <form autocomplete="off" id="workForm">
        <input type="text" id="workInput" />
        <button id="workButton" onclick="onSubmitWork()">Add</button>
      </form>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First day</th>
            <th>Second day</th>
            <th>Third day</th>
            <th>Fourth day</th>
            <th>Fifth day</th>
            <th>Sixth day</th>
            <th>Seventh day</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">
          <tr class="row0"></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

#### JS code

```
// handle submit button
function onSubmitWork() {
  // Get input element by id
  const workInput = document.getElementById('workInput');

  // Get tbody element
  const tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');

  // Get total rows "tr"
  const nbRows = tbody.childElementCount;

  // Get cuurent row by css class name
  const currentRow = document.querySelector(`.row${nbRows - 1}`);
  console.log(currentRow.childElementCount);

  // Check the number of td we have in the current row
  if (currentRow.childElementCount <= 5) {
    addWork(workInput.value, nbRows);
  } else {
    addRow(nbRows);
    addWork(workInput.value, nbRows);
  }
}

// Add a new "td"
function addWork(inputValue, nbRows) {
  let node = document.createElement('TD');
  const text = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  node.appendChild(text);

  const row = document.querySelector(`.row${nbRows - 1}`);
  row.appendChild(node);
}

// Add a new row "tr"
function addRow(nbRows) {
  let row = document.createElement('TR');

  // Create a new css clss name for the new row
  const rowClass = `row${nbRows}`;
  row.classList.add(rowClass);
  document.getElementById('tbody').appendChild(row);
}
```

here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-ey1aqv?file=script.js)